# Cannot connect to Kubernetes cluster on container engine

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to deploy a python app (a REST API) on GCP using the guide here https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/quickstart-container-engine. As a part of that, I spun up a k8s cluster and got it's credentials. Now I can't access it:

`$ kubectl get no
the server doesn't have a resource type "nodes"
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.2", GitCommit:"08e099554f3c31f6e6f07b448ab3ed78d0520507", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-01-12T04:57:25Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Error from server (Forbidden): the server does not allow access to the requested resource`

The server doesn't recognize any of the common resources. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would say: Start over: It looks like you missed a setup step or a setup error (And then most likely something with the etcd).

Comment: That was the case. It worked fine when I deleted the cluster and created one again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an intermittent error as pointed out. Worked fine on a retry.